# Dyson formula vs Kubo formula for 1pt functions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, perturbation-theory

I have a basic confusion about the relation between the in-in and the in-out  1pt functions, in perturbation theory. Or in other terms: I am not able to resolve a conflict between the Kubo formula and the Dyson expansion.  I would like to understand how to make compatible these two well known perturbative expansions when applied to the 1pt functions.

Let's recall the Dyson perturbative expansion for the split of the hamiltonian $H=H_0+H_{int}$ (where in general $H_{int}$ hence $H$ can depend on time via external currents, but I will assume $H_0$ does not), specialized to 1pt functions
$$
\langle \Omega|\phi(x)|\Omega\rangle=\frac{\langle0|T\left(\phi(x)S\right)|0\rangle}{\langle0|S|0\rangle}\,,\qquad S\equiv T\mathrm{exp}-i\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}H_I(\tau)d\tau
$$
where ${}_{I}$ stands for the interaction picture relative to $H_0$, that is $H_0|0\rangle=0$,  $H_I=H_{int}(\phi_I)$ and $\phi_I(t,\vec{x})=e^{i (t-t_0) H_0 }\phi(t_0,\vec{x})e^{-i (t-t_0) H_0}$. By $|\Omega\rangle$ I mean the true vacuum of the full Hamiltonian $H$.

Since the Heisenberg field evolves as $\phi(t,x)=V(t,t_0)^{-1}\phi(t_0,\vec{x})V(t,t_0)$ where $V(t,t^\prime)$ is the exact time-evolution operator, $i\partial_t V(t,t^\prime)=H(t) V(t,t^\prime)$, the relation to $\phi_I(t,\vec{x})$ is
$$
\phi=U(t,t_0)^{-1}\phi_I(x)U(t,t_0)\qquad  U=e^{i(t-t_0)H_0}V(t,t_0)%\,,\qquad  V(t,t_0)^{-1}e^{-i(t-t_0)H_0}\phi_I(x)e^{i(t-t_0)H_0}V(t,t_0)\,.
$$
The $U$ solves the evolution equation $i\partial_t U(t,t_0)=H_I(t)U(t,t_0)$ with initial condition $U(t_0,t_0)=1$ so the solution being
$$
U(t,t_0)=T\mathrm{exp}-i\int_{t_0}^t d\tau H_I(\tau)\,.
$$
Therefore, the 1pt function can as well be written as as in-in correlator
$$
\langle\Omega|\phi(t,\vec{x})|\Omega\rangle=\langle\Omega |U(t,t_0)^{-1}\phi_I(t,\vec{x})U(t,t_0)|\Omega\rangle=\langle\Omega|\left(\bar{T}\mathrm{exp}i\int_{t_0}^t d\tau H_I(\tau)\right) \, \phi_I(t,\vec{x}) \, \left( T\mathrm{exp}-i\int_{t_0}^t d\tau H_I(\tau)\right)|\Omega\rangle
$$
where $\bar{T}$ is the anti-time ordering.

Let's now imagine choosing the perturbation  $$H_{int}=\int d^3x \lambda(t,\vec{x}) \phi^n(t,\vec{x})$$ (for example linear, $n=1$, to keep it as simple as possible),  for some external current $\lambda(t,\vec{x})$ which start zero in the past, become non-zero for some finite time range, and then drops to zero again at some time in the futue of $t$. Therefore, since $H=H_0$ for very early times, it should be expected that $|\Omega\rangle$ at $t_0=-\infty$ is indeed $|0\rangle$, up to a phase $e^{i\alpha}$.
$$
|\Omega\rangle=e^{i\alpha}|0\rangle\Longrightarrow  \langle\Omega|\phi(t,\vec{x})|\Omega\rangle=\langle0|\left(\bar{T}\mathrm{exp}i\int_{t_0}^t d\tau H_I(\tau)\right) \, \phi_I(t,\vec{x}) \, \left( T\mathrm{exp}-i\int_{t_0}^t d\tau H_I(\tau)\right)|0\rangle
$$
This latter equation on the righthand side gives the Kubo formula when expanded to linear order in $\lambda$,
$$
\mbox{Kubo: }\qquad \langle\Omega|\phi(t,\vec{x})|\Omega\rangle=\langle0|\phi_I(t,\vec{x})|0\rangle+i\int_{-\infty}^{t}d\tau \int d^3\vec{y}  \lambda(\tau,\vec{y}) \langle0| [\phi^n(\tau,\vec{y}),\phi(t,\vec{x})]|0\rangle+ o(\lambda^2)
$$
whereas from Dyson equation above, to the same order,
\begin{align}
\mbox{Dyson: }\qquad \langle\Omega|\phi(t,\vec{x})|\Omega\rangle= & \langle0|\phi_I(t,\vec{x})|0\rangle \\ 
&+i\langle0|\phi_I(t,\vec{x})|0\rangle \int d^4y \lambda(y) \langle0| \phi^n(y)|0\rangle -i\int d^4y \lambda(y) \langle0| T\phi^n(\tau,\vec{y})\phi(t,\vec{x})|0\rangle+ o(\lambda^2)
\end{align}
where the time integration domain is the entire real line. To make things even simpler, let's imagine $n=1$ and that in the $H_0$ theory $\langle0|\phi|0\rangle=0$. The two expression are then
$$
\mbox{Kubo: }\qquad \langle\Omega|\phi(t,\vec{x})|\Omega\rangle=i\int_{-\infty}^{t}d\tau \int d^3\vec{y}  \lambda(\tau,\vec{y}) \langle0| [\phi(\tau,\vec{y}),\phi(t,\vec{x})]|0\rangle+ o(\lambda^2)
$$
whereas from Dyson equation above, to the same order,
\begin{align}
\mbox{Dyson: }\qquad \langle\Omega|\phi(t,\vec{x})|\Omega\rangle= -i\int d^4y \lambda(y) \langle0| T\phi(\tau,\vec{y})\phi(t,\vec{x})|0\rangle+ o(\lambda^2)
\end{align}

**Question: how are these two equations for Kubo and Dyson expansion (or their generalization with $n\neq 1$ above) compatible with each other?**

Notice that the Kubo formula is manifestly causal, with no contribution from the source contributing from spacelike separated points. On the other hand, the Dyson one does not look very causal, as points at spacelike separations contribute under the integral. In fact the difference between these two expression is an integral over a Wightman function
thanks to the identity $T\phi_1\phi_2=\theta(t_2-t_1)[\phi_2,\phi_1]+\phi_1 \phi_2$, which I have a hard time imagine it's integrating to zero. Moreover, the $x$-dependence of $\lambda(x)$ is essentially arbitrary so it seams that one could even remove the integration. **I am doing some basic error in the derivation above, but which one?**

**Clarification** Just to clarify the question: I think I see how to go from one formula to the other with formal manipulations. For example, I could get Dyson from the in-in expression in the following way
$$
\langle\Omega|\phi(t,\vec{x})|\Omega\rangle=\langle\Omega |U(t,t_0)^{-1}\phi_I(t,\vec{x})U(t,t_0)|\Omega\rangle=
\langle\Omega |U(t,t_0)^{-1}U(-t_0,t)^{-1} U(-t_0,t)\phi_I(t,\vec{x})U(t,t_0)|\Omega\rangle=\langle\Omega |U(t_0,-t_0)  U(-t_0,t)\phi_I(t,\vec{x})U(t,t_0)|\Omega\rangle
$$
where I've used various composition properties of $U$, and then choosed again $t_0=-\infty$ so that $U^\dagger(+\infty,-\infty)|\Omega\rangle=S^\dagger|\Omega\rangle=e^{i\beta}|0\rangle$ for some phase (notice that $|\Omega\rangle=|\Omega,t_0\rangle$ is defined at $t_0$ and it should match |0\rangle (possibly up to another phase) for $t=t_0$ or smaller, since $\lambda\rightarrow 0$ and $H=H_0$ at early times). Finally, the phase is traded for the normalization and since everything else is already time-ordered one gets the Dyson formula.
$$
\langle\Omega|\phi(t,\vec{x})|\Omega\rangle=\frac{\langle0 |T\phi_I(t,\vec{x})S|0\rangle}{\langle0 |S|0\rangle}
$$

My actual question is whether these formal manipulations are correct or not,  given that the explicit example worked out at the liner order in the perturbation does not look consistent with these equations.

**Hint of what's perhaps going on**
I suspect the issue is with the statement $S^\dagger|\Omega\rangle=e^{i\beta}|0\rangle$ because the model is exactly solvable for $n=1$ and the true ground state $|\Omega\rangle$ is given by a coherent state of the Fock free states, hence $S^\dagger|\Omega\rangle=e^{i\beta}|0\rangle+\mbox{several other states}$. I am not however convinced because Peskin-Schroeder exercise 4.1 solves the model exactly resumming precisely the perturbative series that looks problematic... Also coleman in the QFT lecture notes solves this model resumming the Dyson series. I think the Dyson series is actually still working because of the implici $i\epsilon$ prescription that moves the asymptotic time $t_0$ slightly off the real line allowing to project on the vacuum state $|0\rangle$ anyway.  But then I am still not understanding what's going on, as the two expressions seem hardly consistent with each other at the 1st perturbative order.

Comment: added extra comment on a possible direction to resolve the issue

Comment: ok, I think I understand it now: the two expressions are indeed different, and correctly so.   It's the issue pointed out in the last paragraph of the question, where $S^\dagger |0>$ is not proportional to vacuum: it's that with $\lambda$ turned on, the vacuum isn't stationary and only when working with the in-out correlators that one recovers the Dyson formula (which is what we usually do for the funcional generators, taking the $\lambda$ to zero to the end to recover a stationary vacuum again). The Kubo is instead calculating an in-in correlator, they are just differnt object, that's all.